# Book definition verification of boundary manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, definition, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be an n-dim topological manifold with boundary, A chart for M is a pair $(U,\phi)$ where $\phi: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a map such that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism onto an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $p\in M$ is not a boundary point, in which case, restricting the coordinate map to $\phi^{-1}{(int\mathbb{H}^n)}$ is an interior chart whose domain contains p.

My question is:
Isn't the author assuming that $\phi$ is continuous? Notice, he sais: "$\phi: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a map such that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism onto an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$."  I know that homeomorphisms are continuous.If $\phi$ is continuous...  then can I say that $\phi^{-1}(int\mathbb{H}^n)$ is open in $U$.

Comment: Homeomorphisms are continuous maps (in particular).  An atlas for a topological manifold with boundary will involves *some* charts that map onto "half-spaces".  Presumably this is where the notation $\mathbb H^n$ comes into the definition you are summarizing.  It might be expeditious to tell Readers where you found this definition, i.e. cite your source so some gaps can be filled in.

Comment: Yes, but how can he assert that $\phi^{-1}(int \mathbb{H}^n)$ is open in $U$, without assuming that $\phi :U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous (as a map to $\mathbb{R}^n$, rather than to the open subsets) @hardmath

Comment: I'm guessing you've left out the description of $U$ other than as a part of the pair $(U,\phi)$.  That's one reason I recommend citing your source.

Comment: What i've written above is a summary of page 25 and 26 in introduction to smooth manifolds by Lee (with the Errata in mind)

Comment: ah wait, I think $\phi$ is continuous in either case, since extending the codomain of a continuous function to a space that contains the codomain is still continuous and since the interior is open, therefore what he said makes sense